# Status=Forbidden, StatusCode=403] response when making an Apex callout

Tags: apex, api

[image]I'm having an issue getting a positive response(200 code) when making a callout to SBA API.  I use the same authentication headers and endpoint in Postman and the response is successful.

However, currently that's not the case for me in Salesforce.  Below is my callout method code.  The JSON is in a separate method.  I have tried to do the callout without the body and headers and still receive the same response code.  Anyone ever run into this issue and resolved it?

**Code**

```
public static String makeCallout(String jsonstring) {
    
    //call out logic here
    ETranDetails__c etranDetails = ETranDetails__c.getOrgDefaults();
    HttpResponse response;
    
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setHeader('Authorization', etranDetails.API_Key__c);
    request.setHeader('Vendor-Key', etranDetails.Vendor_Key__c);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setEndpoint(etranDetails.Forgiveness_Endpoint__c);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setTimeout(120000);
    request.setBody(jsonstring);
    response = http.send(request);
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 403 means you trying to access something you dont have permission to. So check if the authorization and vendor-key parameters are correct

Comment: Nagendra, the authorization key and vendor key that I'm using in Salesforce are completely identical to what I use in Postman.  Postman returned a positive response.

Comment: 403 is a response being sent to you from the other system, you should check with them, or ensure that you are actually providing the service with the credentials you think you're providing.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of PostMan with the header details ? you can erase the authentication key if you want.

Comment: Nagendra, I added a picture of the headers for Postman and abbreviated the api and vendor keys.  Note: Please ignore the bad request message.  That happens if I do a call with the same data back to back.  The first response is always a 200 response code.

Comment: Whenever there is different response from any rest client vs Apex, best thing to try is compare the header fields and endpoint in RestClient and Apex (Chrome developer tools, -> Network tab). This way you can avoid any initial mistake. Because if you getting a proper response from Rest Client then you should get the same response from Apex too, if all setup is proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing my Postman setup to my Apex code again, I realized that my endpoint was missing the "/api/ppp_loan_forgiveness_requests/" section at the end. After making that change, I no longer receive the 403 error code. Now I receive the 400 error code. That said, this question is resolved I say as 400 is a different issue(field validation). Thanks for the assistance everyone.

Comment: you should mark this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

You may have messed up the authorization header. The [documentation](https://ussbaforgiveness.github.io/) shows:

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Which means you probably meant to:

```
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Token '+etranDetails.API_Key__c);
```

Comment: sfdcfox, it would be nice if that was the case.  My custom setting field, API_Key__c, has Token included just as the documentation instructs.